# How do I access the "permanent" IPv6 address?

Tags: ipv6, google-wifi

In Windows 11 (same as 10 I think), the command `ipconfig` gives something like this

```
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : lan
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : ...:5c69
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : ...:d046
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::...:73ee%14
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168...
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::...:d531%14
                                       192.168...
```

Now when I setup the Google Nest Pro router it shows this host with a different IPv6 address but I go ahead and add the port forwarding (443, I am running a local https server), then go to GoDaddy and add an AAAA record.

- If I use the "IPv6 Address" in the above (...5c69), access to my domain from outside timed out.
- If I use the "Temporary IPv6 Address (...d046), it will success but then I have to set it again because it changes after some time as it is "Temporary".

What can I do to make the ...5c69 address accessible from outside?

## Update (2 days after initial post)

The "Temporary" address (...d046) still works. I don't know how long it would last, it is totally up to the router and I guess once I reset the router I will have to update it. Given all that, it would still be good to find a permanent solution.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what kind of "port forwarding" you've added?

Comment: Edited, it was 443 https

Comment: That's not what I meant. Can you describe the actual "port forwarding" function that you have in the router's configuration? Does it ask you to specify IPv6 addresses?

Comment: Google Nest Wifi Pro uses Google Home App to config the Wifi. The port forwarding will list all devices by the host name, and giving info of their IP address and MAC address. However there it is not an option to specify the IP address, regardless it is IPv4 or IPv6.

Comment: For IPv4, it is possible to reserve the DHCP IP address for the device, but it is not an option for IPv6

Comment: The point grawity is (probably) trying to make: With IPv6, you wouldn't want _port forwarding_, but firewall rules instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, the permanent IP address does work, just that the way it was tested has problems.

After a week, the "Temporary" IPv6 address is no longer appear in `ipconfig` output. But the permanent IP (...5c69) is still there.

Updated GoDaddy with the permanent IP, then connect to a VPS I own and run

```
ping -6 [mydomain]
```

Although this is not successful due to the firewall does not allow `ping`, it correctly resolves the domain to the IPv6 address. Then I run

```
curl https://[mydomain]
```

when locally running my web app. It took a while longer than usual, but ended up showing the expected web content.

I guess last time I was not patient enough to wait for the browser cache etc to update.